# PHP String parse error

Tags: string, php

I am getting this error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING
```

When I do this call:

```
<?php
inlcude '../global.php';
?>
```

And the global.php file is there, so I don't think that is the problem.  I am trying to call global.php as the first thing that happens in the script.

Anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Would you mind sharing relevant snippets of code where you suspect this error is coming out from?

Comment: Verbal -1 for `<blink>`.

Comment: Whoops - programming late at night...thanks...misspelling lol...my bad - very embarrassing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
inlcude '../global.php';
^^^^^^^
```

Spellcheck says "boo!".

Answer (score 6):

You are using :

```
<?php
inlcude '../global.php';
?>
```

You should be using :

```
<?php
include '../global.php';
?>
```

Note the typo : you must use [**`include`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), and not **`inlcude`** ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Typo there  it should be `include`  try below code

```
include '../global.php';
```